# simple HTML can't getJSON from servlet (java) + mysql

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, json, getjson

I am trying to get JSON from a simple HTML but I can't do it successfully :c .. I generate JSON from a java Servlet, from MySQL, like this ...

**Prueba.java (Servlet)**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try{

        Connection conn = ConexionBD.obtenerConexion();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM grifo where id=1");

            while(rs.next()){
                String grifo = rs.getString("grifo");
                String distrito = rs.getString("distrito");
                String latitud = rs.getString("latitud");
                String longitud = rs.getString("longitud");

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("grifo", grifo);
                json.put("distrito", distrito);
                json.put("latitud", latitud);
                json.put("longitud", longitud);

                    out.print(json);
            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            out.print(e);
        }
}
```

So, when I run this, I get the JSON:

```
{"grifo":"Grifo Libertad","distrito":"San Juan de Lurigancho",
"latitud":"-123.059028347924","longitud":"93.945783454234234"}
```

In my java project I have another page called [index.jsp](http://freetexthost.com/4xp6w0kxc0), that gets the JSON.

I get the json correctly, but when I create a **.html** (in desktop: file:///C:/Users/Jhonatan/Desktop/prueba.html in the web browser) with the same code:
http://freetexthost.com/w2xgabhaks

I can't get the JSON, just display NOTHING! Is there a problem with the file on the server (.jsp), at some other location (desktop: .html) or maybe with the database (mysql)?

How does https://graph.facebook.com/zombies work then?

Thanks for all of you!

Comment: IS the jSON object available to your JSP?

Comment: you mean, if i get this? http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/1864/json.jpg

Comment: try putting your html file also in server location and access it as http://localhost:8080/whatever/filename.html, not desktop and see if it works. If it is in desktop I think browsers makes some path guessing to make dynamic requests work.

Comment: that works ... but is there any way put it on desktop or any location on PC...
The real problem is: i need to get the json (from mysql) to do an android application with phonegap ... i thought with java must be more easier :c

Comment: Also, the Content-Type header should be set to "application/json"

Comment: What exactly you want to do with android and Java as if you need some data to your page on HTML then it will cross domain call so check also that. So can you please mention what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at what the JS console says? My guess is that it will throw something like `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

JavaScript requests have a *same-origin* policy. What you're trying to do is a [cross-origin request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

The simple fix is for your server to return the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

But I recommend you read [all about this](http://enable-cors.org/) and understand what are the implications.